# detect older versions of ie using less.js and then use filter?

Tags: javascript, less

I have a function which applies gradients in less as :

```
.linearGradient(@begin: black, @end: white, @switch : 100%) {
  background: @begin;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@begin), color-stop(@switch, @end));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
  background: linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=@top, endColorstr=@bottom,GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

I want to be able to test for a versions < IE10 and use filter else just use css3.

Edit: Additional questions
Is there a way to test for browsers?

Comment: Regarding the additional question: You can test for IE<10 using conditional comments, and you can test for WebKit using a certain CSS hack: https://gist.github.com/1551173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother making a test; IE10 doesn't support the `filter` property.